# Assertion failed: xdrPtr && xdrPtr == *xdrLPP, file xx.cpp, line 2349

Tags: c++builder, c++builder-2010

Have a system build using C++ Builder 2010 that after running for about 20 hours it starts firing of assertion failures.

> Assertion failed: xdrPtr && xdrPtr == *xdrLPP, file xx.cpp, line 2349

Tried google on it like crazy but not much info. Some people seem to refer a bunch of different assertions in *xx.cpp* to shortcomings in the exception handling in C++ Builder. But I haven't found anything referencing this particular line in the file.

We have integrated *madExcept* and it seems like somewhere along the way this catches an out of memory exception, but not sure if it's connected. No matter what an assertion triggering doesn't seem correct.

**Edit:**
I found an instance of a if-statement that as part of it's statement used a function that could throw an exception. I wonder if this could be the culprit somehow messing up the flow of the exception handling or something?

Consider

```
if(foo() == 0) {
 ...
}
```

wrapped in a try catch block.
If an exception is thrown from within foo() so that no int is returned here how will the if statement react? I'm thinking it still might try to finish executing that line and this performing the if check on the return of the function which will barf since no int was returned. Is this well defined or is this undefined behaviour?
Wouldn't

```
int fooStatus = foo();
if(fooStatus == 0) {
 ...
}
```

be better (or should I say safer)?

**Edit 2:**

I just managed to get the assertion on my dev machine (the application just standing idle) without any exception about memory popping up and the app only consuming around 100 mb. So they were probably not connected.

Will try to see if I can catch it again and see around where it barfs.

**Edit 3:**

Managed to catch it. First comes an assertion failure notice like explained. Then the debugger shows me this exception notification.

[image: Debugger Exception Notification]

If I break it takes me here in the code

[image: Break in code]

It actually highlights the first code line after

```
pConnection->Open();
```

But it seems I can change this to anything and that line is still highlighted. So my guess is that the error is in the code above it somehow. I have seen more reports about people getting this type of assertion failure when working with databases in RAD Studio... hmmmm.

**Update:**

I found a thread that recursively called it's own *Execute* function if it wasn't able to reach the DB server. I think this is at least part of the issue. This will just keep on trying and as more and more worker threads spawn and also keep trying it can only end in disaster.

Comment: any errors shown after the assert is because the condition in the assert failed and you tried to keep running the program.  They really mean nothing.  You have to follow the stacktrace backwards to find out what happened.

Answer (score 0):

If madExcept is hinting that you have an out of memory condition, the assert could fail if the pointers are NULL (i.e. the allocation failed).  What are the values of xdrPtr and xdrLPP when the assert occurs?  Can you trace back to where they are allocated?

I would start looking for memory leaks.

Comment: I just managed to get the assertion on my dev machine (the application just standing idle) without any exception about memory popping up and the app only consuming around 100mb. So they were probably not connected.

Comment: what about following the stack trace on the assert, can you see anything then?  Which of the conditions is the assert hitting?